# Encrypted string length

Tags: java, encryption, javax.crypto

hi¡ i'm having a problem with crypto a string to obtain a user's pdf. It shows a error that below:

javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

the code is there:

```
public void getPDF(WebRequest request, ResourceResponse response, Model model,
                   @RequestParam("cif") String cif, 
                   @RequestParam("cuenta") String cuenta, 
                   @RequestParam("objectId") String encryptedObjectId) throws Exception{

    log.info("Inicio metodo getPDF");

    OutputStream os = response.getPortletOutputStream();


     try {

        CipherHelper cipher = new CipherHelper(CipherHelper.TRIPLE_DES_ALGORITHM, InterfazConstantes.ENCRYPTION_KEY, InterfazConstantes.ENCRYPTION_SHIFT);
        String objectId = cipher.decrypt(encryptedObjectId, true);
```

---

```
public String getEncryptedObjectID() {
    try {
        CipherHelper cipher = new CipherHelper(CipherHelper.TRIPLE_DES_ALGORITHM, InterfazConstantes.ENCRYPTION_KEY, InterfazConstantes.ENCRYPTION_SHIFT);
        encryptedObjectID = cipher.encrypt(objectID, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return encryptedObjectID;
}
```

** I stablished the encryptedObject id has 40 length, but it not solve to problem jet.

The trace of error is:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.6]
```

Can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: Without knowing what `CipherHelper` does, it will be impossible to help here. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: This shows always this error, although my string encryptedObjectId has  8,16,32 or 64 lenght. It's some confused, and I think that the problem could be related with the encryp/decrypt of this param.

Comment: I've voted to close. Without a more complete code example we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to using String for binary data (encrypted text = `byte[]`).
And then using a default encoding.

```
String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);// Single byte encoding
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
```

Comment: Should I pass a byte[] to the cipher.encrypt? thanks

Comment: Depends on the API. I do not know the class CipherHelper, it may be, that hexadecimal representation from bytes are used, in which case my answer is moot, but `encrypt` normally should receive text (String) and yield binary data (`byte[]`) and `decrypt` inverse.